# Probability problem (boys and girls sitting on a bench)

Tags: probability

3 girls and 4 boys are sitting on a bench in a park. If a boy and a girl sit next to each other they make a pair. What's the probability that there is exactly one pair on the bench?

I've been trying to solve this with no luck, the answer is 2/35.

Answer (score 3):

The only way for there to be one pair is if all the girls sit on one side, and all the boys sit on the other. There are $2$ ways for this to occur, out of a total of $7!/(3!4!) = 35$ permutations.

Comment: I knew there are 2 ways for this to occur, but I couldn't understand how to get the 35 permutations, Why did you divide by 3!4!?

Comment: The number $$\binom{7}{3} = \frac{7!}{3!4!}$$ is the number of ways we can select three of the seven seats for the girls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @dkisonas There are $n!$ ways to order $n$ items, but we divide by $k!$  for each item that is repeated $k$ times to avoid overcounting groups where order shouldn't matter (e.g. we don't care what order the boys are in among themselves -- just where they are sitting in general). Google "permutations with repetition" for more info.

Answer (score 2):

1 couple : girls sit together and  the boys sit together on the bench, or boys sit together and girls sit together.

$3!$ ways of seating the girls, 4! ways of seating the boys. So $3!4!$ ways of seating girls and boys, ×2, (first the girls and then boys, and in reverse order).

So altogether  $2×3!4!$ ways.

Ways of seating $7$ people on a bench : $7!$

Probability $p(1)$ of having only 1 couple :

$p(1)$ = $\frac{2×3!4!}{7!}$ = $\frac {2}{35}$.

Comment: very nice approach